# How to Host a Struts/Spring Web application project on Website for beginners?

Tags: java, web-hosting

How to deploy java web project on website, how to host simple java web app online on website.

Any free web hosting websites? for beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku provide some free plane which is ideal for experimenting with cloud applications in a limited sandbox.
[heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

If you have git account, and install heroku in local machine then use follow

```
commend:
 git add .

 git commit -m "Added a Procfile."

 heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
...

 heroku create
Creating arcane-lowlands-8408... done, stack is cedar-14
http://arcane-lowlands-8408.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:arcane-lowlands-8408.git
Git remote heroku added

 git push heroku master
...
-----> Java app detected
...
-----> Launching... done
       http://arcane-lowlands-8408.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

And it's easy to deploy web app on it 
[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java) 
 is a doc of heroku to deploye the java web app doc.

Also you can use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), it's provide one year free plane with limit of data.

Comment: Thanks sure it helps :)

Comment: @HemanthPeela if it's help then please accept the answer, so it may help other. Thank you! Happy to help :)